# How to make an ON/OFF circuit to light up an LED, using only relays and one normally open button?

Tags: led, relay, normally-open

I'm new in this world. I tried latching relays. I only achieved keeping the LED ON but I'm not able to turn it off with the same button. Any idea?

Comment: You need a Toggle Relay.

Comment: Latching relay with two coils and DPDT. One throw switch the coils.

Comment: What's the LED? (It matters.) What's the power supply? (It matters.) And you can do this with semiconductors and a single momentary switch. Do you prefer that? Or are you only interested in relay solutions? (That matters, too.)

Comment: Are you aware that you can do this with just a [latching push button](https://www.google.com/search?q=latching+button&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single-coil ratchet relay and a momentary push button switch may be used to toggle the lamp on and off.

[image]

A ratchet relay is a type of latching relay.

Its contacts change over with a single energisation pulse to its coil and revert on the subsequent pulse.

A low cost solution would be to use a latching push button switch instead.

It's a 'push-to-on / push-to-off' type of switch.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest ON/OFF circuit that I know that's works look looks this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM88O2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But the relay needs to be able to energized at Vsup/2 or able to work at 2 Sup if we decided to use Vsup/2 relay. OR slightly less than Vsup.
I used two 9V relays in 12V circuit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It worked for me. Really appreciate it!